# p:inputText with p:ajax calls f:viewParam Converter

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

We do have a small page which is using the viewParam to convert a given Id to a concrete object. This converter is called on leaving (blur) of an inputText field, which is validated. Why? Could I rework this, so that the converter is not called every time?

This is annoying, because the converter calls the set-method for the corresponding object in the BackingBean and this bean is then null, if the page is called the first time for creating this object.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.object}"
                 converter="#{objectConverter}"
                 converterMessage="#{msgs['converter.msg.object']}"/>
    <f:viewAction action="#{bean.init}"/>
</f:metadata>

<p:inputText id="text" value="#{cc.attrs.value}"
             styleClass="inputTextValidated"
             required="#{cc.attrs.required}"
             requiredMessage="#{cc.attrs.requiredmessage}"
             label="text" validatorMessage="#{cc.attrs.msg}" title="#cc.attrs.title}"
             readonly="#{cc.attrs.readOnly}">
            <cc:insertChildren/>
            <p:ajax update="msg_text" event="blur"/>
</p:inputText>
<p>
  <p:message id="msg_text" for="text" display="msg"/>
</p>
```

If we do not use a converter but just the viewAction to convert the Id to the corresponding object (or create a new object if applicable), everything is fine. Is this the only/correct solution for this problem?

We do use primefaces 6.1 with CDI. The converter is a @Named and @ApplicationScoped bean implementing the Converter Interface.

Using p:fragment around the inputtext-field did not help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the nature of how JSF works.  If you want to not have it do that I suggest you check out OminFaces ViewParam:  http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/viewParam

From their documentation:

> Stateless mode to avoid unnecessary conversion, validation and model
>   updating on postbacks The standard UIViewParameter implementation
>   calls the model setter again after postback. This is not always
>   desired when being bound to a view scoped bean and can lead to
>   performance problems when combined with an expensive converter. To
>   solve this, this component by default stores the submitted value as a
>   component property instead of in the model (and thus in the view state
>   in case the binding is to a view scoped bean).
>
> The standard UIViewParameter implementation calls the converter and
>   validators again on postbacks. This is not always desired when you
>   have e.g. a required="true", but the parameter is not retained on form
>   submit. You would need to retain it on every single command
>   link/button by . To solve this, this component doesn't call
>   the converter and validators again on postbacks.

Comment: No problem. Edited for clarity.

Comment: And upvoted ;-) and comment removed (this pne too tomorrow)